# Using HangFire to call action delegate produces exception

Tags: hangfire

I'm trying to use HangFire to call an action method on a class.  From the code below, the action method works correctly if called outside of HangFire, but throws an exception when using HangFire.  I also tried using `Invoke()` as stated by other similar posts.

> Expression body should be of type
>   'MethodCallExpression'(Parameter'methodCall')'

I'd like to figure out how to have HangFire execute this type of method if possible.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new ActionTest();

        // Calling this method prints out Hello World correctly
        a.DoAction();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");

        // Call this method from HangFire produces exception: Expression body should be of type 'MethodCallExpression'(Parameter'methodCall')'
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ActionTest>(a => a.DoAction());
    }
}


public class ActionTest
{
    public ActionTest()
    {
        DoAction = WriteHello;
    }
    public Action DoAction;

    public void WriteHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other way than wrapping the call to `DoAction` in a genuine method :

```
public class ActionTest
{
    public ActionTest()
    {
        DoAction = WriteHello;
    }
    public Action DoAction;

    public void InvokeAction()
    {
        DoAction();
    }

    public void WriteHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

then

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ActionTest>(a => a.InvokeAction());
```